# Is the composition of uniformly distributed functions uniformly distributed?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure, curves

Let $\mathcal{I}:=[0,1]$.

**Def:** A measurable function $\varphi:\mathcal{I}\rightarrow \mathcal{I}$ is said to be uniformly distributed with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\Lambda$ if, for any measurable set $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{I}$,
$$
\Lambda_1[\varphi^{\star}(\mathcal{A})]=\Lambda_1(\mathcal{A})
$$
where $\varphi^{\star}(\mathcal{A}):=\{t\in \mathcal{I} \text{ s.t. } \varphi(t)\in \mathcal{A}\cap \mathcal{R}(\varphi)\}$ and $\mathcal{R}(\varphi)$ is the range of $\varphi$.

---

Consider the measurable functions $\varphi:\mathcal{I}\rightarrow\mathcal{I}$ and $\psi:\mathcal{I}\rightarrow\mathcal{I}$ and assume these are uniformly distributed. 
For $t\in \mathcal{I}$, construct the function
$$
\beta:\mathcal{I}\rightarrow \mathcal{I} \text{ with } \beta(t):=\varphi(\psi(t))
$$

**I want to show that $\beta$ is uniformly distributed [from Sagan "Space-Filling Curves" p.110].**

**Proof (attempt):**

We want to show that $\forall \mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{I}$ with $\mathcal{A}$ measurable
$$
\Lambda_1(\beta^{\star}(\mathcal{A}))= \Lambda_1(\mathcal{A})
$$
We have that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\beta^{\star}(\mathcal{A})&:=\{t \in \mathcal{I} \text{ s.t. } \beta(t)\in \mathcal{A}\cap \mathcal{R}(\beta)\}=\{t \in \mathcal{I} \text{ s.t. } \varphi(t)\in  \overbrace{\mathcal{A} \cap \varphi_{\star}(\mathcal{R}(\varphi))}^{\subseteq \mathcal{A}\cap \mathcal{R}(\varphi)} \}\subseteq \{t \in \mathcal{I} \text{ s.t. } \varphi(t) \in \mathcal{A}\cap \mathcal{R}(\varphi)\}\\
&:=\varphi^{\star}(\mathcal{A})
\end{aligned}
$$
We know that
$$
\Lambda_1(\varphi^{\star}(\mathcal{A}))=\Lambda_1(\mathcal{A})
$$
How can this imply
$$
\Lambda_1(\beta^{\star}(\mathcal{A}))=\Lambda_1(\mathcal{A})
$$
? It can be if and only if $\Lambda_1(\beta^{\star}(\mathcal{A}))=\Lambda_1(\varphi^{\star}(\mathcal{A}))$ ??

Comment: More simply, you know that $L(f^{-1}(B))=L(B)$ and that $L(g^{-1}(B))=L(B)$ for every Borel subset $B$ (yes, I changed notations) and you are asking whether $L(h^{-1}(B))=L(B)$, where $h=f\circ g$. Well, $h^{-1}(B)=g^{-1}(C)$ with $C=f^{-1}(B)$ hence $L(h^{-1}(B))=L(g^{-1}(C))=L(C)=L(f^{-1}(B))=L(B)$, end of story.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Did have a question: how do I know that $C:=f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable in order to conclude that $L(g^{-1}(C))=L(C)$? Thanks

Comment: Because $f$ is assumed to be measurable, of course.